# User Authentication with ExpressJS and CouchDB

Tags: javascript, session, authentication, express, couchdb

I'm trying to login a CouchDB User into my express app via a frontend form and store the login in the session. What have so far is the following:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var couchUser = require('express-user-couchdb');
var session = require('express-session');

var login = require('./routes/login');

var app = express();

app.use(couchUser({
    users: 'http://localhost:5984/_users',
    request_defaults: {
        auth: {
            user: 'admin',
            pass: 'adminpw'
        }
    }
}));

app.use(session({ secret: 'secretstring'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', login);
```

and in my login.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var couchUser = require('express-user-couchdb');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', {title: 'Login'});
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    // Don't know what to put here
    //res.send(req.body.username)
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't know how to go on in my login.js route. Any help is appreciated.

Update - Since I couldn't get the code underneath to work because I didn't understand it completely, research lead me to the following solution:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {

    var options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:5984/_session',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            "name": "admin",
            "password": "password"
        }
    };


    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log('authenticated');
        }else{
            console.log('not authenticated');
            res.redirect('/')
        }
    });
});
```

When I do the same request via HttpRequester I get Statuscode 200 and {"ok":true,"name":null,"roles":["_admin"]} .. but via nodejs it won't do it even though it should be the same?!?

Answer (score 0):

To validate user credentials against CouchDB just follow the example from [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/intro/security.html#creating-a-new-user).

`curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_session -d 'name=jan&password=apple'`

After successful authentication you can keep CouchDB credentials the [session storage](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

I created a "proof of concept" code which is probably even not correct since *i am not nodejs expert*. But after some tuning it should work.

```
var http = require('http');

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    var session = req.session;
    request.post('http://localhost:5984/_session')
        .auth(req.data.username, req.data.password, true)
        .on('response', function(response) {
            if(response.statusCode == 200) {
                session.couchSession = req.data.username + ':' + req.data.password;
                res.status(200);
                res.send();
            } else {
                res.status(400);
                res.send('Wrong credentials');
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks fpr your answer. So in you opinion I don't need the express-user-couchdb middleware? And second: Where should I execute this curl request? Is it meant to be called from nodejs?

Comment: It doesn't have to be specifically cURL request. I would rather use `http` or `request` library. Depending on your use case I would use this middleware or not. Another thing is that it's not heavily maintained (last update to the source code was 2 years ago; plus there was CouchDB 2 release few weeks ago!).